# Controlling HoldForm while mapping

Tags: evaluation, hold

If I execute

```
A = {Sin, Cos, Tan}
B = {ArcSin, ArcCos, ArcTan}
#[[1]]@#[[2]]@x & /@ Transpose[{A, B}]
```

the output is

```
{x,x,x}
```

which is to be expected. However, what I want is

```
{Sin[ArcSin[x]], Cos[ArcCos[x]], Tan[ArcTan[x]]}
```

Knowing that `HoldForm[Sin[ArcSin[x]]]` outputs `Sin[ArcSin[x]]`, I tried

```
A = {Sin, Cos, Tan}
B = {ArcSin, ArcCos, ArcTan}
HoldForm[#[[1]]@#[[2]]@x] & /@ Transpose[{A, B}]
```

but this gives me

```
{{Sin,ArcSin}[[1]][{Sin,ArcSin}[[2]][x]],{Cos,ArcCos}[[1]][{Cos,ArcCos}[[2]][x]],{Tan,ArcTan}[[1]][{Tan,ArcTan}[[2]][x]]}
```

Much like Zach Braff's morning routine, this output is plagued by too much `Hold`.

How can I `Hold` the form of the expression without `Hold`ing the evaluation of `Part`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Hold[]`, consider using `Inactive[]`:

```
MapThread[Inactive[#1][Inactive[#2][x]] &, {{Sin, Cos, Tan}, {ArcSin, ArcCos, ArcTan}}]
```

(equivalently, `MapThread[Inactivate[#1[#2[x]]] &, {{Sin, Cos, Tan}, {ArcSin, ArcCos, ArcTan}}]`)

which would look like this on the front end:

[image: inactivated functions]

To remove `Inactive[]`:

```
Activate[%]
  {x, x, x}
```

In older versions, you can try `Defer[]` or `HoldForm[]` instead of `Inactive[]`, e.g.

```
HoldForm[Sin][HoldForm[ArcSin][x]]
```

and to remove the held evaluation,

```
ReleaseHold[%]
```

Answer (score 5):

Several alternatives:

```
Defer[#@#2@x] & @@@ Transpose[{A, B}] 
HoldForm[#@#2@x] & @@@ Transpose[{A, B}] 
MapThread[Compose[HoldForm@#, HoldForm@#2, x] &, {A, B}]
HoldForm[a[b @ x]] /. Thread[{a, b} -> #] & /@ Transpose[{A, B}] 
With[{a = #[[1]], b = #[[2]]}, HoldForm[a[b@x]]] & /@ Transpose[{A, B}]
```

all give

> {Sin[ArcSin[x]],Cos[ArcCos[x]],Tan[ArcTan[x]]}

Answer (score 3):

Another approach using operator forms (and avoiding slots, e.g., #):

```
Through @* Thread[HoldForm @* A @* B] @ x
```

> {Sin[ArcSin[x]],Cos[ArcCos[x]],Tan[ArcTan[x]]}